# How do_action funtion works with path parameter?

Tags: plugins

I am editing some plugin but stuck with this line of code.  I have read about do_action function but I don't understand this below code. Can someone help me with this.   Is this a path ? how to trace it ?

```
        do_action('cuar/core/page/before-' . $part);
        do_action('cuar/core/page/before-' . $part . '?slug=' . $slug);
```

Thank you

Comment: That looks like it's something to do with [WP Customer Area](https://wp-customerarea.com/). Third-party plugin support is off-topic here. You should try contacting the plugin developers via [their support streams](https://wp-customerarea.com/resources/).

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `do_action` is the `$tag`, a string. As far as the API is concerned, there's no special meaning to the contents of the `$tag`, it's just a unique name that's matched as a whole to hooked actions of the same name.

The structure and naming convention of tags is up to the plugin developer. The example you provide may in fact be a path, but whatever purpose that has is going to be specific to that plugin. The possible values of `$part` and `$slug` and the event that triggers the action is information you will need to seek from the plugin's developer / support.